# Python Readability Score for an article (using Spacy)

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I've looped though the text of 100 articles to grade them using [spacy](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy_readability): The scoring methods I'm usaing are:

- Dale Chall Readability Index
- Coleman-Liau Index
- Automated Readability Index

However, I don't know how to interpret the results.

For example, the [Coleman-Liau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dale%E2%80%93Chall_readability_formula) Index shold be around 14 or 15 based on grade level. 
However, I get scores of 1245 and 1633

Another example, [Dale-Chall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dale%E2%80%93Chall_readability_formula) readability formula should be something like 4.5, or 5.6. 
However, I get scores of 245 and 340

Is there something I need to do with these scores?

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
from spacy_readability import Readability

articles = pd.read_csv('articles.csv')

# get the title and body of text from the articles
text = articles[['title','body']]
df = pd.DataFrame(text)

for i in range(1, 100):
    # select the body of text to score on the readability index
    text = df.iloc[i, 1]
    doc = nlp(text)
    # Print the cell containing the article title
    print(df.iloc[i,0])
    # score the text
    print("dale chall", doc._.dale_chall)
    print("coleman", doc._.coleman_liau_index)
    print("readability", doc._.automated_readability_index)
```

Example output:
'10 ways how machine learning is helping people innovate.' 
Dale-Chall: 255.843042857 
Coleman-Liau: 1245.025714285 
Automated Readability Index: 998.556428571

Comment: The code is relatively simple: https://github.com/mholtzscher/spacy_readability/blob/master/spacy_readability/__init__.py . Look carefully at your data (not just the title) to figure out what's going on. This is not really a programming question.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. Great to read through the code that calculates these numbers. I tried it out by directly pasting in the body of text and got the same results. I also tried it out with various texts, and sentences. However, could someone put these numbers in context? A sentence gets around 4.5, while the entire body of text gets 255 on the Dale-Chall Index. Does this simply the higher the score, the more effort required to read through it? Thanks

Comment: I didn't get unusual results like this with the texts I tried, so I really don't know. Maybe your article text isn't cleaned properly? You can try the texts in the tests to see if there's something wrong with your installation: https://github.com/mholtzscher/spacy_readability/tree/master/tests

Comment: I still get arbitrary results even when using the sample texts. I'm just trying to follow this simple ReadMe https://github.com/mholtzscher/spacy_readability/blob/master/README.md
. I always get 7.57 for flesch_kincaid_grade_level (no matter what text I use) and I get scores in the thousands for coleman_liau_index and automated_readability_index. I've spent hours on this and have got nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using pre-implemented libraries or see the source code. This is my repo, but I'll share it since I think it can help you. https://github.com/brucewlee/lftk

```
# bash
pip install lftk
pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

# python
import spacy
import lftk

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Your text")
LFTK = lftk.Extractor(docs = doc)

# extract readability features
extracted_features = LFTK.extract(features = ["cole", "auto"])
```